# How can I use DictationRecognizer() on wpf application?

Tags: c#, windows, voice-recognition, dictation

it works on unity. I need to work with wpf but when tried with wpf here Dictatoin recognizer not is recognized, though speech assembly is linked.

I need a simple way to use following/equivalent on wpf :

`DictationRecognizer dictationRecognizer = new DictationRecognizer();//not recognized.`

can you recommend a way/solution for this?

Comment: Check [speechrecognitionengine class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: nothing form that class works like DictationR. did.